# Additivity of polynomial functions in characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, and $f\in k[x]$ such that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b\in k$.  Does it follow that $f(x)=\sum c_ix^{p^i}$ for some $c_i\in k$?

I'm fairly certain this is true, although a proof alludes me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no", with a counterexample being (for example) $k=\mathbb F_p$ and $f = x(x^p-x)$.

However, if $k$ is infinite, then the answer is "yes". Equivalently, the answer is always "yes" if you replace the condition "$f\left(a+b\right)=f\left(a\right)+f\left(b\right)$ for all $a,b\in k$" by "$f\left(X+Y\right)=f\left(X\right)+f\left(Y\right)$ in the polynomial ring $k\left[X,Y\right]$". This follows from Theorem A.2 in [Keith Conrad's *Carlitz Extensions*](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/carlitz.pdf).